# What's wrong with "we want moshiach now"?

Tags: messiah, chabad

Tzivos Hashem, the international Lubavitch youth group, has "We Want Moshiach Now!" in its logo, and Lubavitch children are taught to say and sing that phrase.

I have heard that some authorities have publicly expressed disagreement with, even protested, the use of the phrase.

- On what basis? (Citations, please, where possible.)
- How do they reconcile their disagreement with our constant prayers for *mashiach* now? For example, in *sh'mone esre* we say "וקבצנו יחד מהרה… לארצנו" and "ומלוך עלינו מהרה" and "וכסא דוד עבדך מהרה לתוכה תכין" and "את צמח דוד עבדך מהרה תצמיח".‎

Comment: Those prayers are for Mashiach (among other things) _soon_.

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=98b&format=text though the actual answer is probably the same reason we don't go around chanting "we want techiyat hameitim now".

Comment: I don't think there *has* to be Torah-based answer to this question. IMHO a more likely answer would be politics.

Comment: @Danield It is always easier shrug off an opposition which is just playing politics.

Answer (score 14):

A demanding "tone" in prayer is deemed improper. Consider what Shimon ben Shetach said to Choni heMeagel after successfully demanding rain from Hashem (vowing not to leave a drawn circle until it was given, modifying the request multiple times):

> שלח לו שמעון בן שטח ואמר לו, צריך אתה לינדות; אבל מה אעשה לך, שאתה מתחטא לפני המקום כבן שמתחטא לפני אביו, והוא עושה לו רצונו.  עליך הכתוב אומר, "ישמח אביך, ואימך; ותגל, יולדתך" (משלי כג,כה). ([תענית יט א](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=10&daf=19&format=pdf))‏

As I understand it, the lyrics of the song are:

> Am yisroel, have no fear
>
> Moshiach will be here this year
>
> Am yisroel, have no fear
>
> Moshiach will be here this year
>
> We want moshiach now
>
> We want moshiach now
>
> We want moshiach now
>
> We don't want to wait

The "we don't want to wait" coupled with the "now" seems (to me) a bit demanding in its tone, which is different from a deferential request that mashiach comes now, or soon.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76139/discussion-on-answer-by-josh-waxman-whats-wrong-with-we-want-moshiach-now).

Answer (score 10):

I read online once, forgot the exact source I think it was Rav Shach that it's problematic in its *insistence*, as if God is not doing the best thing by delaying it.

This contradicts the principle that all that H' does is for the good.

Yes, we are supposed to wait for it, but not insist and demand that it comes, as if God is witholding good or that He doesn't know what's best ch'v.

(I'm sure the Rebbe zt'l had good reasons though)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76140/discussion-on-answer-by-ray-whats-wrong-with-we-want-moshiach-now).