# Sing about Moshiach at the end of davening

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot, messiah, song-poetry, chassidic-rebbe

In many kindergartens and preschools, both boys and girls sing at the end of davening, *"We want Moshiach, we want Moshiach now..."*

Was this instituted by the Lubavitcher Rebbe?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/33298/759

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know about the song, "we want moshiach now" it was first sung in 1980 by a group of campers. The Rebbe began clapping along as approval and afterwards encouraged singing it.  The song itself was written by campers and then received the Rebbe's approval after it was first sung in front of him.

As to why this kindergarten does this after davening... This is not part of the nusach and is something this kindergarten decided to include. Perhaps others do the same perhaps they have other songs they chose to use. It should not be surprising that a kindergarten has singing making davening more geared to small children who might otherwise have difficulty focusing for a long time during shachris.

Comment: FYI - Some adults are singing this song after davening, too. It's not just for toddlers, anymore :-)

Comment: my point is not that the song is for toddlers but rather specifically singing it after davening was done by this school and likely they chose to include songs to help the children be more enthusiastic about their prayers.

Comment: Yes, I got that. I was just mentioning that even adults need the enthusiasm - sometimes more than the kids ...